# angular ui-select choices doesnt scroll on ion-view and ion-modal-view but scrolls on ion-popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova, ionic-view, ionic-popup

I have this ui-select on my code. I am building a mobile app with Ionic and AngularJS.

```
<ui-select name="org" ng-model="user.org.selected" theme="selectize" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" style="margin-top: -5px; margin-left: 7px;" required>
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Organization Name" focus-me="true">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices  repeat="item in rea_list | filter: $select.search |limitTo: 20" position="down">
         <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

When i put this code on an ionicPopup, i can scroll the list of options to view the 20 options in the list but if i put this code on my ion-view on a page or in an ionicModal, i cant scroll through the 20 options.

I have no clue why this is so and I cant figure out a way to solve it too. It works perfectly on web but it doesnt work on mobile device.

Comment: you you provide the code pen link, so I can see what you are trying to achieve on the mobile device.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvodmW

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to place it inside ion-content which is supposed to be inside ion-view. This should help with the scrolling.

Comment: it is inside an ion-content and an ion-view  but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This is because native scrolling of Ionic.
You need to add to your `<ion-content>` the `overflow-scroll="true"`directive.

You can also globally enable or disable native scrolling with the `ionicConfigProvider`.

But this will lead to slower scrolling. So try to do this to a `<ion-content>` which is small and doesn't hast huge scrolling stuff in there.